# Working with dates function in php

Tags: php, json, date

I am a newbie to PHP programming and I came across this:

```json
{
    "dates": [
        "2015-07-23",
        "2015-07-22"
    ],
    "EN": [
        "1",
        "1"
    ],
    "AK": [
        "0",
        "0"
    ],
    "GA": [
        "0",
        "0"
    ]
}
```

What does it mean?

Comment: it means nothing. it's just text, which happens to look like a json-encoded data structure.

Comment: It looks like a json, which has array of `dates`, `EN`, `AK`, and `GA`

Answer (score 1):

Its just JSON data.

```
{
   "dates":[
       "2015-07-23",
       "2015-07-22"],
   "EN":["1","1"],
   "AK":["0","0"],
   "GA":["0","0"]
}
```

The whole thing is a JSON object. Dates, EN, AK and GA are JSON arrays within the object. The representation is in key: value form.

dates, EN, AK and GA are the keys and the data after the ":" is the value.

Objects are enclosed within { }. A JSON array is enclosed by [ ].

Note: You can have embedded objects within objects. For associating multiple values with a key, an array is used. Here the key "dates" has two values, "2015-07-23" and "2015-07-22" and hence represents a JSON array. Key-value pairs are separated using ",".